# Как передать массив не во вью, а вместе с вью на фронт в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, blade

Хочу передать массив из контроллера. Этот массив должен быть доступен скрипту на фронтенде. Если я даже передаю массив во вью, я не могу сообразить как его сохранить на фронт в виде массива, читаемого скриптом. Как это сделать удобнее всего?
Скрипту массив должен быть доступен в любое время, а не только при загрузке страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Задача решена из шаблонизатора:

```
    <script>
        var app = @json($rolesPermissions);
    </script>
```

где, $rolesPermissions - это массив.

Answer (score 0):

Запишите ваш массив в сессию и пользуйтесь на здоровье.

```
 $myArray = ['key' => 'value' ];
    session(['usefulData' => $myArray]);
```